# JSON и работа со словарями

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Нужно написать функцию age_count, которая принимает json-строку следующего вида:

```
{
    "workers": [
        {"name": "Имя1", "age": 34, "occupation": "Программист"},
        {"name": "Имя2", "age": 24, "occupation": "Программист"},
        {"name": "Имя3", "age": 40, "occupation": "Грузчик"}
    ]
}
```

Далее в функции нужно посчитать средний возраст по каждой из профессий и сохранить в файл age.json этот возраст в следующем виде:

```
{
    "Программист": 29.0,
    "Грузчик": 40.0
}
```

Также результирующий json должен быть выведен на экран в конце выполнения функции.

Вот тут я перевёл json-строку и получаю словарь, который имеет один ключ и одно значение, но в значение список из словарей.

```
import json
    def age_count(x):
        x = json.loads('{ "workers": [{"name": "Имя1", "age": 34, "occupation": "Программист"}, {"name": "Имя2", "age": 24, "occupation": "Программист"}, {"name": "Имя3", "age": 40, "occupation": "Грузчик"} ] }')
```

Как найти среднее значение в списке из разных словарей?

Думал попробовать сделать, так

```
if x[1][occupation] == "Программист":
            m_sum = sum(x[1][age].values)/len(x[1][age])
```

Но не уверен что это правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s ='''
{
    "workers": [
        {"name": "Имя1", "age": 34, "occupation": "Программист"},
        {"name": "Имя2", "age": 24, "occupation": "Программист"},
        {"name": "Имя3", "age": 40, "occupation": "Грузчик"}
    ]
}
'''

import json


r = {}
for x in json.loads(s)['workers'] :
    r.setdefault(x["occupation"],[]).append(x["age"])
for x in r.keys() :
    r[x] = sum(r[x])/len(r[x])
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

import json
def age_count(x):

```
s = ('{ "workers": [{"name": "Имя1", "age": 34, "occupation": "Программист"}, {"name": "Имя2", "age": 24, "occupation": "Программист"}, {"name": "Имя3", "age": 40, "occupation": "Грузчик"} ] }')


r = {}
```

for x in json.loads(s)['workers'] :

```
r.setdefault(x["occupation"],[]).append(x["age"])
```

for x in r.keys() :

```
r[x] = sum(r[x])/len(r[x])
```

print(r)

with open("input.txt") as f: age_count(f.read())